# Is there a way to replace values in json from strings to list of strings

Tags: python, json, regex, string

I am trying to transform all values in json as list of strings in json. 
Even the nested dictionaries values should have their values in as list

From :

```
    {
        "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", 
        "City": "AIBONITO", 
        "Name" : [
          {
            "EstimatedPopulation": "abc" 
            "LocationType": "PRIMARY", 
            "Zipcode": "00705"
          }
        ] 
    }
```

To :

```
    {
        "ZipCodeType": ["STANDARD"], 
        "City": ["AIBONITO"], 
        "Name" : [
          {
            "EstimatedPopulation": ["abc"], 
            "LocationType": ["PRIMARY"], 
            "Zipcode": ["00705"]
          }
        ] 
    }
```

Comment: create new dicts with the values as lists, using your old jsons. save back to json format. done.

Comment: Why would you need to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple regex

```
j="""
{
    "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", 
    "City": "AIBONITO", 
    "Name" : [
      {
        "EstimatedPopulation": "abc" 
        "LocationType": "PRIMARY", 
        "Zipcode": "00705"
      }
    ] 
}
"""
import re
result = re.sub(r':\s*("[^"]*")',r': [\1]', j)
```

Comment: You could, but why would you? Why expose yourself to the risk of a quote inside one of those values blowing everything up when there's an actual parser right in the standard library?

Comment: A quote inside the string would not be parsed (see `[^"]`).
The question was tagged with the `regex` tag, thus I am suggesting a regex solution.
Obviously you can use a context-free-grammar, like the native `json` library does, but why ? this question could be answered with a finite-state-transducer.

Comment: Yes, and that's the *problem*. A line `"foo": "\"bar\"",` becomes `"foo": ["\"]bar\"",`, which is no longer valid JSON. The OP almost by definition doesn't know what they're doing, just because they've tagged it regex doesn't mean that's an appropriate tool; they're relying on the answerers to be able to tell them that.

Comment: You're right, an escaped quote could be an issue, also could be solved with a regex.